# Is there a way to have a list of all the currencies from the iphone api?

Tags: iphone

I wanted to allow the user to choose a currency from a list of currencies. Do i have to hardcode all the currencies in the code or can i get it from the api, somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[NSLocale ISOCurrencyCodes]`. It gives you an array of all the ISO currency codes as strings.

[(Link to documentation)](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLocale/ISOCurrencyCodes)

Answer (score 2):

```
CFLocaleCopyCommonISOCurrencyCodes();
CFLocaleCopyISOCurrencyCodes();
[NSLocale commonISOCurrencyCodes];
[NSLocale ISOCurrencyCodes];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the list of world currencies doesn't change that often, you could go get some current definitive list and add them to your bundle as a property list (an array of strings, if that works, or a dictionary). You can load the plist with framework methods such as `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile` or `arrayWithContentsOfFile`. Storing the list in a resource is preferable to hard-coding them into your app; and since that list doesn't change that often, I don't see any reason to load them from the internet every time.